# Using gridfs-stream findOne I am no able to persist changes to db

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs

I'm super new to this. I am able to save files to the database using gridfs-stream, but I have not been able to persist changes to the metadata.  I can find the file using gfs.findOne, and when I console the file, I see the changes, but I am doing something wrong since they do not persist.`

```
 // update route_____________________________________________
router.get('/images/:_id/edit', (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params._id;
  // code to update filename
  Image.findById(id)
    .then((image) => {
      image.filename = 'stargazer';
      image.save(function(err,updatedImage) {
      });
    });

  // code to update metadata
  gfs.findOne({ _id: id}, function(err, file) {
    {$set: { file.metadata.description ='test metadata description' } }
    res.send(file);
  })
});`
```